# How to disable Double Click in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, touchscreen

I have a Windows 8.1 tablet that runs but it has a very sensitive touchscreen. e.g. selecting a file in File Explorer results in launching. Internet Explorer keeps going in and out of zoom.

I figure double click is rarely used in 8.1. I might as well disable it to see how it goes. But I can't seem to find a way to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: `Control Panel` -> `Mouse`: adjust double-click speed to slower calibre...

Comment: It is the opposite of what I want to do. It will make legitimate double clicks harder to trigger.